# Workmanager (registerPeriodicTask) with flutter but my application crushes everytime the it runs in background

Tags: java, flutter, dart

Am working on a flutter application that has to retrieve and update my sqlite database in backgound. And to achieve this, am trying to setup and use workmanager plugin provided by flutter. But everytime it runs in background, it displays 'unfortunately, myapp has stopped'.

here is my main.dart

```
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager.executeTask((task, inputData){
    try {
      var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
      if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
        // I am connected to a mobile network.
        if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
          print('connected');
        }
      } else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
        // I am connected to a wifi network.
        if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
          print('connected');
        }
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      print('not connected');
    }
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Workmanager.initialize(
      callbackDispatcher, // The top level function, aka callbackDispatcher
      isInDebugMode: 
          false // If enabled it will post a notification whenever the task is running. Handy for debugging tasks
      );
  // Periodic task registration
  Workmanager.registerPeriodicTask("2", "syncfirebase",
      // When no frequency is provided the default 15 minutes is set.
      // Minimum frequency is 15 min. Android will automatically change your frequency to 15 min if you have configured a lower frequency.
      frequency: Duration(minutes: 15),
      initialDelay: Duration(seconds: 10),
      constraints: Constraints(networkType: NetworkType.connected));

  runApp(new MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Also, gets this error on initial app installation.E/flutter (18969): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: ServicesBinding.defaultBinaryMessenger was accessed before the binding was initialized.
E/flutter (18969): If you're running an application and need to access the binary messenger before `runApp()` has been called (for example, during plugin initialization), then you need to explicitly call the `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` first.

Answer (score -1):

If I had to guess, you're missing a call to `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` in your `callbackDispatcher`. The `callbackDispatcher` is the entrypoint for the background isolate (effectively a Dart thread) that `WorkManager` is spawning, so you'll need to re-initialize the `WidgetsFlutterBinding` (this should really be done by the plugin, but it doesn't look like the author decided to do that).